# How can I search for multiple string values and return string value found?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am using Zapier to parse the body of Indeed Job application emails into a Google sheet cell.

I want to then search for the job location (Rushden, Northampton, Kettering, Wellingborough) and return the location that has been found ie Rushden, Northampton etc...

I would be very grateful if someobody could help me out with this - it is beyond my Google sheets capabilities.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

With towns in B1:E1 etc, data cells A2:A4 etc. in B2 copied across to E2.. and B2:E2.. down as required:

```
=if(iserror(SEARCH(B$1,$A2)>0),"",B$1)
```

Answer (score 0):

based on very little info you provided in your question, you are probably looking for formula variation of `ARRAYFORMULA` and `VLOOKUP` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B10:B14, B22:C25, 2, 0))
```

[image]